# Maxima: how to roll (or shift) a list

Tags: list, maxima

What is the simplest way to roll a list ?

Consider the following list :

```
myList : [0,1,4,6,3]
```

I am looking for a `roll()` function that would do :

```
(%i0) roll(myList,1)
(%o0) [3,0,1,4,6]


(%i1) roll(myList,-1)
(%o1) [1,4,6,3,0]
```

I can achieve the same result by calling :

```
myItem : pop(myList)
myList : append(myList,myItem)
```

Problem is that this works in one direction only (there is no `pop_back()` function to my knowledge (?)) and that it is a two liner. Any better way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there isn't a built-in function for that. But I think you can use `rest` to get the effect you want.

```
(%i10) rotate (e, n) :=
   if atom(e) then e
   else block ([a : args(e)],
          apply (op(e),
                 append (rest (a, length(a) - n), rest (a, -n)))) $
(%i11) foo : [a, b, c, d, e, f, g];
(%o11)                       [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
(%i12) rotate (foo, 2);
(%o12)                       [f, g, a, b, c, d, e]
(%i13) rotate (foo, 7);
(%o13)                       [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

This works for all expressions, not just lists.

```
(%i16) rotate (f(1,2,3), 2);
(%o16)                            f(2, 3, 1)
```

This implementation doesn't take negative `n` or `n` greater than the number of arguments, although I think it would be easy to handle that.

I've assumed that `rotate` moves elements at lesser indices into greater indices. Again, if you want the default to go in the other direction, I think it would be easy to do that.

EDIT: Actually it isn't necessary to separate out `op(e)` and `args(e)`. You can call `rest(e, ...)` when `e` is not a list and it does the right thing. So a more concise version is:

```
rotate (e, n) :=
   if atom(e) then e
   else append (rest (e, length(e) - n), rest (e, -n)) $
```